# String length error - saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, model-view-controller, entity

I encountered this weird error while trying to save data to database on MS Azure.

> the field must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '1'

I am quite certain that I cant fix this on Azure side because I have tried all string data types (char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, text with values like 255 or max). The string with 1 character really worked and got saved to DB.

I managed to avoid this error by setting `context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` but that in not the desired solution.

I suppose that it must be specified somewhere in the code but I have no idea where the length of this string is specified and therefore how to edit it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It is hard to give advice without seeing the code in question.

Comment: @mjwills I made a new project and simulated the functionality but I am not able to get the same error although the input in both is the same and one gives the error, the other one doesnt. I guess I will make a new project and copy my code there, make new Entity Data Model and hope it works.